# Finding the K th lexicographically substring of a given string when the duplicate substrings are allowed

Tags: c++, string, suffix-array

I want to find *lexicographically Kth smallest substring* of a given string when the duplicate substrings are allowed.

Suppose we are given a string ***abc*** then its substrings in lexicographical order are {a,ab,abc,b,c}, now suppose we are given K = 3 then ans is *abc*.

Now suppose we are given string ***aaa*** then all its substrings are **{a,a,a,aa,aaa,aa}** so now if K = 4 then we output **aa**.

However I came across the following code on ***codeforces*** but i am not able to understand it. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
char s [MaxN];
bool b [MaxN];
int k, n;

void solve (vector <int> v)
{
   int i, j;
   int64 p, q;
   char c;

   vector <int> w;
   for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
   {
       p = q = 0;
       w.clear ();
       for (j = 0; j < (int) v.size (); j++)
       {
           i = v[j];
           if (s[i] == c)
           {
               w.push_back (i + 1);
               p++;
               q += n - i;
           }
      }
      if (k < q)
          break;
      k -= q;
   }
   assert (c <= 'z');

   putchar (c);
   if (k < p)
       return;
   k -= p;
   solve (w);
}

int main (void)
{
    int i;

    while (scanf (" %s %d", s, &k) != EOF)
    {
         n = (int) strlen (s);
         if (k > ((((int64) n) * (int64) (n + 1)) >> 1LL))
         {
             printf ("No such line.\n");
             continue;
         }
         k--;

         vector <int> v;
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         v.push_back (i);
         solve (v);
         putchar ('\n');
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Here is the link to question http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/128/B

Comment: Is there some part of the code that you don't know what it means?  Have you tried stepping through it with some simple case in order to watch what it does?

Comment: I tried to run it on some small test cases, but in most i got lost in between and also could not figure out Idea behind.
Any new Idea is equally welcome

Answer (score 2):

Shubajit Saha's approach using Suffix Array is incorrect. Consider string `abaab`, its suffixes after sorting are (0-based):

```
2. aab
3. ab
0. abaab
4. b
1. baab
```

According to him, substring `aab` obtained from suffix `2. aab` is smaller than substring `a` obtained from `3. ab`, which is obviously wrong!

A correct approach is using Suffix Automaton + Dynamic Programming. You can learn about it at [CP-Algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html). It's a very well-written tutorial about Suffix Automaton.

The lexicographically k-th substring corresponds to the lexicographically k-th path in the suffix automaton. Therefore after counting the number of paths from each state, we can easily search for the k-th path starting from the root of the automaton. Note that this problem allows duplicate substring, so instead of initializing every state with 1, you should initializing with the number of substrings ending at that state. To do that, please refer to section `Number of occurrences` in the tutorial.

An advantage of this approach is that the time complexity doesn't depend on k, it only depends on the length of the substring (which is at most n). Therefore, k can be much larger than the constraint in the problem (1e10 is fine).

Here is my code in C++: https://codeforces.com/contest/128/submission/72601519

Time complexity is `O(nlgn)`. Though building suffix automaton and traversing it are `O(n)`, we need to sort the states by their length. I use STD sort which is `O(nlgn)`. You can use Counting Sort instead to make it linear.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach to this problem is to construct a suffix array of the given string. Suffix array gives us all the suffixes of a given string in lexicographic-ally sorted order. Once we have all the sorted suffixes of a given string observe that every sub-string of a string is prefix of some suffix. And if we traverse the suffixes in lexicographic-ally ascending order for each suffix of size l gives us l sub-strings , each of which is smaller than the sub-strings obtained from suffixes which are lexicographic-ally greater than the suffix we are considering. Thus we can easily find the Kth smallest sub-string by marinating a count of sub-strings.

Actually suffix array is used to solve a more difficult version of this problem where you are given Q queries of finding Kth sub-strings, where K is different in each query.

Regarding the code you in your question, since you have to find the kth sub-string only once, the solution approach essentially uses the same logic but with different implementation.